# Asynchronous Web Crawler with Pyppeteer - Python

Tags: python, asynchronous

This weekend I've been working on a small asynchronous web crawler built on top of asyncio. The webpages that I'm crawling from have Javascript that needs to be executed in order for me to grab the information I want. Hence, I'm using pyppeteer as the main driver for my crawler.

I'm looking for some feedback on what I've coded up so far, as async, asyncio, and pyppeteer are all still fairly new to me and I feel I'm making some pretty big, naive mistakes in my approach. I'm also using this as an opportunity to learn. Any feedback is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

```py
import asyncio
import lxml.html as html
from pyppeteer import launch

seed = 'https://example.com' # Base seed URL

def get_links(url, text):
    """"Returns a list of valid URLs from a given document.

    Args:
        url: the url of the page
        text: the HTML document

    Returns:
        l: a list of valid urls to crawl
    """
    h = html.fromstring(text)
    l = [a.attrib['href'] for a in h.xpath('//a')]
    l = [seed+a for a in filter(lambda a: 'http' not in a, l)]  # Removes external URLs.
    return l

async def _crawl(browser, que):
    """Crawls a webpage.

    Args:
        browser: a pyppeteer browser object
        que: the main task queue
    """
    page = await browser.newPage() # Creates a new page
    seen = set()
    while not que.empty():
        url = await que.get() # Retrieves a url from the task queue

        if url in seen: # If the url has already been crawled, complete the task and continue
            que.task_done()
            continue

        seen.add(url)

        await page.goto(url, timeout=10000) # go to the current url
        text = await page.content() # get the page content
        links = get_links(page.url, text) # retrieve valid links to be crawled

        for link in links:
            if link in seen:
                continue

            que.put_nowait(link) # put an unseen link into the task queue

        print('put %3d links from %s into queue' % (len(links), url))
        que.task_done() # complete the task


class CrawlerPool:
    """A worker pool for managing crawlers."""
    def __init__(self, loop, coro, max_crawlers):
        self.loop = loop
        self.q = asyncio.Queue(loop=self.loop)
        self.coro = coro
        self.max_crawlers = max_crawlers

    async def run(self):
        browser = await launch()
        crawlers = []

        for _ in range(self.max_crawlers):
            crawlers.append(asyncio.create_task(self.coro(browser, self.q)))

        await self.q.join()

        for c in crawlers:
            c.cancel()

        await browser.close()
        print('done.')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
cp = CrawlerPool(loop, _crawl, 5)

cp.q.put_nowait(seed)

loop.run_until_complete(cp.run())
```

**Edit** Added additional comments to code and concerns.

The concerns I have are mostly a result of my ignorance to asynchronous functions in Python and the pyppeteer library. I'm ideally just looking for feedback if what I've written makes sense in an asynchronous model.

**Additional Edit**

After looking over and reviewing it with a coworker, this snippet seems to work fine. I believe that the for loop containing all the `c.cancel()` calls can even be removed as they are redundant.

Comment: Could you add a short explanation for how your code works, and why you made any unorthodox choices if you did?

Comment: See edit. I wish I could give a better sense of my concerns - I'm still learning and so the I'm afraid that my questions won't make sense and feel that if someone could point to anything that doesn't seem right, that'd be appreciated. Thanks!